# Problema con diseño de Xamarin forms, linea separadora de list view no llega hasta la orilla izquierda

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, grid

¿Por qué la linea separadora entre los items de mi listview no llega hasta el lado izquierdo de la pantalla?, no logro encontrar algún error en el código

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                         x:Class="AppJoynder.Page4Reserva"
                         Title="Reserva"
                         Icon="calendar">
                <ContentPage.Content>
                    <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />                          
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#0B5894" Padding="0,50,0,0" Grid.Row="0">
                      <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />               
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"  Text="Reservaciones" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />  
                    </Grid>            
                    <ListView SeparatorVisibility="Default" Margin="2,0,2,0" x:Name="lstReservaciones" BackgroundColor="White" HasUnevenRows="true"  >  
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                    <DataTemplate>  
                        <ViewCell> 
                    <StackLayout Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                    <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />                                     
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />                                    
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Area}" Margin="10,0,0,0"   VerticalOptions="End" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></Label>

                    <Label Text="{Binding Fecha}" Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ></Label>

                    <Label Text="{Binding Reservas}" Grid.Row="3"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></Label>                               
                    <BoxView  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" WidthRequest="3" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start"/> 
                    <Image Source="calen" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Image>
                    <Image Source="moon" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Image>                                                              
                     </Grid>
                       </StackLayout> 
                       </ViewCell>  
                      </DataTemplate>  
                     </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                    </ListView>  
                   </StackLayout> 
                   </Grid>
                </ContentPage.Content>
            </ContentPage>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Intentaste quitando el margin izquierdo de estas propiedades, y del BoxView (que me imagino que es la franja de color )iniciarlo en Grid.Column="0".

```
    <ListView SeparatorVisibility="Default" Margin="0,0,2,0" x:Name="lstReservaciones" BackgroundColor="White" HasUnevenRows="true" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >  


<BoxView  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" WidthRequest="3" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
```

Tambien puedes darle un  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" al ListView General.